# Elementary set theory problems and "proof techniques"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A\to B$ be a function.. Consider the following functions on the powersets of $A$ and $B$:

$$f[-]:\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B), f[S] = \{y\in B | \exists x\in S, f(x)=y\}$$
$$f^{-1}[-]:\mathcal P(B)\to\mathcal P(A), f^{-1}[T] = \{x\in A | f(x)\in T\}$$

Show that for every $S,S'\subseteq A, T,T' \subseteq B$:
$S\subseteq f^{-1}[f[S]]$ and $f[f^{-1}[T]]\subseteq T$

My attempt:

$f^{-1}[f[S]]=\{x\in A|f(x)\in\{y\in B|\exists x\in S, f(x)=y\}\}$. And this for me looks pretty obvious that $S$ must be included in this set, but how do I really prove it? What's there to say about it?

Comment: The standard way to prove that $S\subset Z$ (for any set $Z$) is to prove, for all $x$, that $x\in S \implies x\in Z$. So you need to prove the following statement: if $x\in S$, then $x\in f^{-1}[f[S]]$. Can you do that from the definition you wrote down? (or rather, the corrected definition where you don't use $x$ to mean two different things)

Comment: @GregMartin I don't think, I mean, not really, I don't think I can think this through, so, $f[S]$ is the set with all $y\in B$ such that $f(x)=y$ and $x$ is $\in S$, and $f^{-1}[f[S]]$ is the set with all $x \in A$ such that $f(x) \in f[S]$ so all $x$ in $A$ not $S$ and I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused about your notation.
Is this version correct?
Assume $f:A \to B$.  Define $g:P(A) \to P(B)$, $S \to f^{-1}(S)$.
$h:P(B) \to P(A)$, $S \to f(S)$.  Show $S \subseteq hg(S)$, $gh(S) \subseteq S$.

$S \subset$ $f^{-1}(f(S)) = hg(S)$.  Proof.
If $x \in S\implies f(x) \in f(S)$, $x \in f^{-1}(f(S))$.

$f(f^{-1}(S)) = gh(S)$ $\subset S$.  Proof.
If $y \in f(f^{-1}(S))\implies \exists x \in f^{-1}(S)$ with $y = f(x)$;
$\exists x$ with $f(x) \in S$ and $y = f(x)\implies y \in S$.

Comment: looks right I think, but can you edit more using mathJax?

Comment: Review my edit please.

Comment: Can you add more details? You just apply $f^{-1}$ on both sides at the first proof?

Comment: No I did not do that to both sides, is used the definitions of f and inverse f as extended for sets. @C.Cristi

Comment: Remove the implication symbols and replace with the orginal English as they mess up the logic. If ... implies ... is absurd. @C.Cristi

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do these proofs: using element chasing, so seeing which elements are part of the most complex side, and then expanding definitions and simplifying towards the simpler side.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\subcalch}[1]{\\ \quad & \quad #1 \\ \quad &}
\newcommand{\subcalc}{\quad \begin{aligned} \quad & \\ \bullet \quad & }
\newcommand{\endsubcalc}{\end{aligned} \\ \\ \cdot \quad &}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\implies}
\newcommand{\when}{\impliedby}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\iff}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
%$

For the first problem, let's see which $\;s\;$ are in the right hand side:
$$\calc
    s \in f^{-1}[f[S]]
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;f^{-1}[-]\;$}
    s \in A \;\land\; f(s) \in f[S]
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;f[-]\;$}
    s \in A \;\land\; f(s) \in B \;\land\; \exists x \in S, f(x) = f(s)
\op\when\hint{left: use $\;S \subseteq A\;$; middle: $\;f : A \to B\;$; right: choose $\;x:=s\;$}
    s \in S \;\land\; \true \;\land\; f(s) = f(s)
\op\equiv\hint{logic: simplify}
    s \in S
\endcalc$$
which (by set extensionality) proves $\;S \subseteq f^{-1}[f[S]]\;$.

The second statement can be proven similarly.

$%
\endgroup
%$