# Prove that some relations are equivalent (set theory)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $g:A\to B$ be a function.. Consider the following functions on the powersets of $A$ and $B$:

$$f[-]:\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B), f[S] = \{y\in B | \exists x\in S, g(x)=y\}$$
$$f^{-1}[-]:\mathcal P(B)\to\mathcal P(A), f^{-1}[T] = \{x\in A | g(x)\in T\}$$

Prove that $g$ injective $\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}[f[S]]=Id_{\mathcal P(A)}\Leftrightarrow f[S^c]\subseteq f[S]^c\forall x\in A$

for the first $2$ relations I did this:

$f$ injective $\implies \forall x_1,x_2\in A$ $x_1 \neq x_2\implies g(x_1)\neq g(x_2)$.

$f^{-1}[f[S]]=\{x\in A|g(x)\in\{y\in B | \exists x \in S\space\space\space s.t. g(x)=y\}\}$.

Let $s_1,s_2\in S$ then $g(s_1),g(s_2)\in f[S]$, $s_1\neq s_2$, but $g(s_1)\neq g(s_2)$, but on the other hand $s_1,s_2\in f^{-1}[f[S]]$ from all this $\implies f^{-1}[f[S]]=Id_{\mathcal P(A)}.$

On the other hand:

$f^{-1}[f[S]]=Id_{\mathcal P(A)}\implies \forall s_1,s_2\in S, s_1\neq s_2\implies f^{-1}[f[S]]=S$ since $S$ is arbitrary $\implies$ g is injective.

For the last 2 I don't know how to prove it however... I'm also not sure if what I did here is right...

Comment: Ug, I tried to edit but your notation is impossible to unravel.  You are using $f$ to represent two different functions. I tried to edit to make one of the functions $g$ but I don't know what parts to make $f$ and what parts to make $g$.  Please edit yourself to make this clear.

Comment: @Michael.  See my translation at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3077369/elementary-set-theory-problems-and-proof-techniques where the editors incorrectly used symbolic logic.

Comment: The first equivalence is wrong. It should say
$f$ in injective $\iff f^{-1}[f[S]] = S$

Comment: And your proof for that equivalence is not correct.

Comment: @Michael I will edit it for you

Comment: @jjagmath why my proof is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ is injective. Take $y \in f[S^c]$. We need to prove that $y \in f[S]^c$. Suppose the contrary, that is $y \in f[S]$.

We have $y \in f[S^c]$, so $y = f(t)$ for some $t \in S^c$, but we also have $y \in f[S]$, so $y = f(s)$ for some $s \in S$. So $f(t) = y = f(s)$. $f$ is injective implies $t=s$, but this can't happen since $t \in S^c$ and $s \in S$.

Now suppose $f[S^c]\subseteq f[S]^c$ for all $S\subseteq A$. Take $a,b \in A$ with $a \ne b$ and set $S= \{a\}$.

We have $b \in S^c$, so $f(b) = f[S^c]\subseteq f[S]^c$. This means $f(b) \not\in f[S]$, whereas $f(a) \in f[S]$, so $f(a)\ne f(b)$ and $f$ is injective.